# vsftpd, restrict FTP user to specific folder

Tags: vsftpd

On my Ubuntu 18.04 server I have created a FTP user (named `ftphtm3`) for which I want to restrict access to folder `/var/www/html3`

Here is what I have done so far:

1. created a FTP directory `/var/ftp/ftphtm3` and bound it to `/var/www/html3`, `mount --bind /var/www/html3 /var/ftp/ftphtm3`
2. changed user's home directory: `usermod -d /var/ftp/ftphtm3/ ftphtm3`
3. in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`: `chroot_local_user=YES`, `chroot_list_enable=YES`

But then, when with filezilla as user `ftphtm3`, I land in `/var/ftp/ftphtml3` BUT I can still go back to neighbours or parent directories (in fact I have access to all my server).

Do you have any idea what I have missed ?

Thank you

p.s: the steps for "restricting" the access come from [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/544850/create-new-vsftpd-user-and-lock-to-specify-home-login-directory) post but I would like if possible to avoid binding directories. I just `ftphtm3` to land in `/var/www/html3` and to only have access on it. That's it.